# save date and time at the value of a button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this button to start the task. When I click the button I want you to save the date and time in the value of the click moment button so when you click on the task register the start time.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="IniciarTarefa" id="acao"></label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <button id="IniciarTarefa" name="IniciarTarefa" class="btn btn-info" >Iniciar Tarefa</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**How am I trying:**

```js
function myFunction() {

var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date+' '+time;
document.getElementById("IniciarTarefa").value = dateTime;
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {

$("#form").submit(function(e){ 
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "./conexaoteste",
      data: $("#form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data)
       {      
    }, 
      error: function(data){
       $(".error_message").removeClass('hide'); // error message
       },
  });
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" id="form"> 
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="IniciarTarefa" id="acao"></label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<button id="IniciarTarefa" name="IniciarTarefa" class="btn btn-info" onclick="myFunction()">Iniciar Tarefa</button>
</div>
</div>  
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="PequenoAlmoco" id="acao"></label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<input type="hidden" id="PequenoAlmoco" name="tarefa" value="Pequeno Almoço">
</div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-info">Pequeno Almoço</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$IniciarTarefa = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["IniciarTarefa"]);
$PequenoAlmoco = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["tarefa"]);    

$sql = "INSERT INTO teste (`IniciarTarefa`, `tarefa`)
VALUES ('$IniciarTarefa', '$PequenoAlmoco')";

$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql);
```

It does not insert into the database table. The problem is on the button with the `id="IniciarTarefa"`

Comment: I think the issue is the button will submit your form without running any of the JS. Try `<button type="button" `...etc so clicking the button doesn't cause a normal postback. Also in the JavaScript it makes no sense to give a value to a button. Buttons are not intended for that. Instead put the value into a hidden field or something

Comment: I think the problem is in your `jquery` how you handle the submit. I tried submitting the form direction via the `action` property of the form and the values are passed correctly

Comment: @ADyson Yes, I have solved the problem by using a hidden field to save the value of the button click

Comment: That's great. You should add the final code of your solution here in the Answers section so that future readers can benefit from it . It can also earn you points from upvotes. Answering your own question is allowed and accepted here.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to use Javascript to do this.

HTML:

```
<button id="IniciarTarefa" name="IniciarTarefa" class="btn btn-info" onclick="myFunction()">Iniciar Tarefa</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction() {

var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date+' '+time;
document.getElementById("IniciarTarefa").value = dateTime;

}

</script>
```

Comment: I edited the question with the form that you tried to insert into the database, but it is not working

Answer (score -1):

the problem is that you only made the query for your msqli-database, right now you only made the query, but you do not execute it. normally this code will work if you just put an queryexecutor inisde of your code.

Comment: The mysqli_query function seems to be there in the code. I don't think this is the problem